# Most efficient way to store a 5 point scale in Django

Tags: python, database, django, django-models

I have the following model for a song:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    rating = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

I want to know if there is a better way to store the rating for a Song, as it is a scale from 1 to 5?
Better in the sense that it will take less space to store the same data in the database.

I have read through the Django documentation and the SmallIntegerField looks like the smallest value field.

But it can hold values ranging from "-32768 to 32767" which is overkill for my needs, as I just want to store 5 unique values (1 through 5).

Is there a smaller field type? Should I use a CharField(max_length=1)?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go one smaller and use a `PositiveSmallIntegerField`, which is guaranteed in all databases to store all integers from 0 to 32,767 (i.e. the positive range of a signed short).

The ideal answer for storage optimization would be to use something like a [bit field](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/datatype-bit.html) where you can store scores in binary, but there is no field type like that in built-in Django that represents numerical values. You'd have to make your own Field that stores a 3-bit unsigned integer, with entails all of the appropriate development required to glue it into Django's ORM.